# How can I change the bullet color of jQuery slider?

Tags: jquery, css

I want to change the default bullet(li) color of jQuery slider into orange color.

If not selected then circle border orange. If selected then circle fill with orange color.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Just Identify the CSS class name used in HTML and update the color code used there in the CSS file.

**EDIT**

From your code in the commemnt

Add the Below style

```
<style>
.carousel-indicators ol li {
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:2px;
    border-color:#F18C16;
}

.carousel-indicators ol li.active{
background-color: #F18C16 !important;
}
</style>
```

Comment: <div>
          <ol class="carousel-indicators">
           <li data-target="#landing_top_slide" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
           <li data-target="#landing_top_slide" data-slide-to="1"></li>
           <li data-target="#landing_top_slide" data-slide-to="2"></li>
           <li data-target="#landing_top_slide" data-slide-to="3"></li>
          </ol>
         </div>

Comment: @Swati Jain I Didnt understand what u mean! Anyway please check the jsfiddle I have created http://jsfiddle.net/e4STr/81/

Comment: i just want the code to change the bullet color (li) of jquery slider

Comment: Edited the Answer, please chk